# Cannot find primary outlet to load 't'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a routing issue in angular 2 that I have spent almost a day trying to figure out what the problem might be,

here is my appmodule routing config

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: "Dashboard", component: DashBoardComponent, children: [
            {
                path: "BenchMark", component: BenchmarkPortalComponent, outlet:"portals",children: [
                    { path: "pendingAccounts", component: PendingAccounts, outlet: "contacts" },
                    { path: "acceptedAccounts", component: AcceptedAccounts, outlet : "contacts" },
                    { path: "", component: BenchmarkPortalComponent }, 
                ]
            },                
            { path: "", component: DashBoardComponent }, 
        ]},

        { path: '', redirectTo: 'DashBoard', pathMatch: 'full' }          

    ])],
```

and my appcomponent has a routeroutlet and the Dashboard component has a named router outlet (name ="portals") and the homecomponent has a named routeroutlet (name = "contacts")

but when I load the page, I see that the app component get loaded and then I have an error that says

```html
core.umd.js:3491EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 't'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 't'
    at getOutlet (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4342:21)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4183:49)
    at eval (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4128:60)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4128:31)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4193:28)
    at eval (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4128:60)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4128:31)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:59784/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4102:16)
```

Am not sure what I am missing here. Help please. I use angular 2.3.1

Comment: Do you have a `*ngIf` around the `<router-outlet>`? Can you show the HTML where and how the router-outlet is placed?

Comment: sorry it took me a while to get back. The problem I am having is if I have a named router putlet under any of my parent components, it doesnt do the routing right. My app component has <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the html while my benchmark component and dashboard components had names components. The moment I removed the named components from the html and the outlets from routing, it started to work fine.

Comment: Routes with an empty path and no children need `pathMatch: 'full'`. I don't know if this solves your problem. A Plunker would be helpful to debug the problem.